# ListView Row Containing Multiple Dynamic Spinners

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I have multiple Spinners inside listview control at particular row.
I fill all spinners dynamically from WebService and all spinner values can change on selected item.

Exp. I have 3 spinner of country and State and City then all this 3 spinners fill from WS and while user select country then on countryselecteditem change all data of state and city. And on State selected item city data change...

And also I scroll and go on that row at that time `getView()` call all 3 selected item and fill all adapters by selected item.

How can I handle 3 spinners inside listview?

Comment: is country,state,city spinner are in same  or different row of listView?

Answer (score 0):

1. Design a ListItem Layout containing 3 spinners of your wish and then set it to ListView Adapter.
2. Then Take An SubClassArrayAdapter with Generic Type of a POJO Class containing 3 IDs (if required take more) like below and set Adapter to ListView.

   ```
   class SpinnersStateInListItem
   {
     private int countrySelectedPosition=0;
     private int stateSelectedPosition=0;
     private int citySelectedPosition=0;
     //here you need to generate respective getters and setter methods.
    }
   ```

   //do the below code to set the SubClassArrayAdapter to listview which you derive from ArrayAdapter class in which you customize your views

   ```
     SubClassArrayAdapter<SpinnersStateInListItem> = new SubClassArrayAdapter<SpinnersStateInListItem>(context,resourceid,listof SpinnersStateInListItem Generic type);
   ```

   inside the getView() of your SubClassArrayAdapter Class, create 3 spinner objects and set array adapter to the first Spinner and then set OnItemSelectedListeners to 3 spinners.
   Then in the first Spinner OnItemSelected method set the ArrayAdapter to 2nd Spinner which will contain the list of State as per Country selected in the first spinner. Then set array Adapter to 3rd Spinner inside 2nd Spinners OnItemSelected method which contain the list of cities as per country selected and state selected. Here you should filter the data as per selected items. When Items are selected immediately save them to SpinnersStateInListItem respective object so that even if you reload the listview all the items state will remain as it is. for example as below.

   ```
   OnItemSelected()
   {
    if(v==firstspinner)
     {
       listofSpinnersStateinListItem.get(listitemposition).setCountrySelectedPosition(spinnerselectposition);  
      } 
     }
   ```

in the sameway as above for state and cities too.

1. Initially you fetch the Data of first country and set it to the First Spinner which simultaneously fetch the first country states and then first country, first state related cities.

Hope this will help you.